# Can a Rake task be documented with a multiline usage accessible from command line?

Tags: ruby, rake, documentation

Rake allows to document succinctly what tasks are doing. But what if a task is intented to provide more information on its usage? Here is a naive attempt to do it with a multiline `desc`

```
desc <<~lid
  Do nothing, even when arguments are provided.
  Usage:
    rake 'users:idle["something", "anotherthing"]'
    rake 'users:idle[, "anotherthing"]' # something is ignored anyway
    rake users:idle # do nothing tersely
lid
task :idle, [:option, :token] => :environment  do |task, fad|
  # Really, do nothing!
end
```

But running `rake --tasks` will only reveal the first line. Is there a way to access the rest of the `desc` through some rake command?

Comment: From one article about rake tasks: _If you can’t explain your rake task in one sentence, that would probably mean that your rake task is doing more than one job and you should consider splitting your rake task._,

Comment: Well, my question arises from a case where the task generates an user, with default implicit values set to the `git config.user.email`/``apg` returns. It also allows to provide custom values through arguments. Yes, it could be splited, but to my taste it wouldn't be that relevant. Thus said, the advise seems nice as a general rule of thumb, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came here with the same problem: I added a parameter with a default value to task, and wanted to document that in enough detail to make sure that folks knew they could pass their own value.

I found that if I made the string longer, it would print the entire string, wrapping it to the next line, which looks terrible.  But if I passed a multiline string, the `-T` output would only print the string up to the end of the first line.

It turns out, this behavior is intentional:

https://ruby.github.io/rake/Rake/DSL.html#method-i-desc

> Descriptions are shown with rake -T (up to the first sentence)
> and rake -D (the entire description).

Given your example above, `rake -D` (or `rake --describe`) should do the trick:

```
$ rake -T
rake idle[option,token]                # Do nothing, even when arguments are provided

$ rake -D
rake idle[option,token]
    Do nothing, even when arguments are provided.
    Usage:
      rake 'users:idle["something", "anotherthing"]'
      rake 'users:idle[, "anotherthing"]' # something is ignored anyway
      rake users:idle # do nothing tersely
```